# Kendo UI for Angular how to save grid state

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

How to save the state of an Angular 2+ Kendo grid. In AngularJS we used getOptions and setOptions (https://www.telerik.com/forums/persist-state-in-angularjs) but I can not find any documentation on how to do this for the latest version of Kendo for Angular (https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/). Thank you in advance for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a good start: https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

we use this approach to store filter state:

```
public state: State = {
        skip: 0,
        take: 5,

        // Initial filter descriptor
        filter: {
          logic: 'and',
          filters: [{ field: 'ProductName', operator: 'contains', value: 'Chef' }]
        }
    };
```

Comment: this will help also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785158/angular-kendo-grid-save-sorted-filtered-grid-in-a-variable/62786091#62786091